# Probability of getting exactly two pairs of socks

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Louay has 10 matching pairs of socks in his drawer. He wakes up in the morning late to his class. Before going out, he randomly draws 8 socks from his drawer. What's the probability of having exactly two pairs of matching socks?

I tried to choose 2 out of 10 pairs, that makes 4 socks, and then picking 4 out of the 16 pairs left to make 8 socks. But this way I'm including the probability of having other pairs of socks.

Then I tried taking one sock from each two so I can eliminate pairs but still I got nowhere near the answer (0.4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $\binom{10}2$ probabilities for choosing two matching pairs.

After that $8$ pairs are left and there are ways $\binom84$ to choose pairs from which Louay only takes one sock.

For each of the $4$ he can choose between $2$ socks (both belonging to the same pair).

So there are:$$\binom{10}2\binom842^4$$possibilities for having exactly $2$ pairs of matching socks.

To find the probability on that event divide by the total number of possibilities of choosing $8$ socks which is $\binom{20}8$.

Final result:$$\frac{\binom{10}2\binom842^4}{\binom{20}8}$$

Answer (score 2):

You want to obtain *both* socks in each of *two from ten* pairs, and *one from two* socks in *each* of *four from eight* pairs.

That gives you exactly two pairs of matching left-*and*-right socks, and four mismatched left-*or*-right socks.

Comment: Isn't this just a restatement of the problem?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I think the italics are very directional. Btw, there was more (it was complete) and it might be that Graham took that away again when my (later) answer appeared.